# failed to execute child process xterm (no such file or directory)

Tags: process, vim, xfce, xterm

When I right click on a file and select vim from upcoming tabs I get this error. Some files of vim should missing. In addition I'm able run vim from bash but can't run from desktop.

Debian 9.8 stretch/xfce

Comment: Try installing xterm

Answer (score 1):

you could try **sudo apt-get install xterm**, see this link:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=228156

Answer (score -1):

You can create a symlink.
The context menu seems to be looking for gnome-terminal, with an xterm fallback. This is the command that fixed it for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal /usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal
```

More info at the first answer in this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169690/panel-run-application-in-terminal-set-terminal-application?newreg=d68cfac07ed44fff903e1ec916b67cac